# SetInterval function is playing audio twice instead of once

Tags: function, settimeout, setinterval

I am running into a wierd issue , I am building a simon says game for freecodecamp, but everytime I run the function below it is playing the audio twice . even though I am only calling the function once , any ideas?

```
change('#8B0000','#E8A5A5','1000','1000','#2');
  var redSound = new 
   Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound1.mp3");  
   var blueSound = new 
 Audio("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound2.mp3");
 var greenSound = new Audio 
("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound3.mp3");
 var yellowSound = new Audio 
 ("https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/simonSound4.mp3"); 


function change(color1, color2,c1,c2,button){
    console.log("Inside Start of function");
var timer = setInterval(function first_color() {
  $(button).css('background',color2);
 if(color2 == '#34d955'){
    greenSound.play()
    } else if(color2 == '#E8A5A5'){
    redSound.play()
    } else if(color2 =='#F3FEA5'){
        yellowSound.play();
    }else if(color2 == '#A5DEFE'){
        blueSound.play()
    }

   setTimeout(change_color, c2);
 }, c1);//  
 function change_color() {
    $(button).css('background',color1);
     clearInterval(timer);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Odds are your timer is being fired twice before your timeout is being called.

Inside of your interval keep track of which sound is playing and return if you already called the method to play the sound.

```
var playing = null;
function change(color1, color2, c1, c2, button) {
    console.log("Inside Start of function");
    var timer = setInterval(function first_color() {
        if (playing == color2) return;
        playing = color2;
        $(button).css('background', color2);
        if (color2 == '#34d955') {
                greenSound.play()
        } else if (color2 == '#E8A5A5') {
            redSound.play()
        } else if (color2 == '#F3FEA5') {
            yellowSound.play();
        } else if (color2 == '#A5DEFE') {
            blueSound.play()
        }

        setTimeout(change_color, c2);
    }, c1);//
    function change_color() {
        $(button).css('background', color1);
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
```

Comment: you are absolutely right , within the 2 second window , the loop played twice , I was able to reduce to 500ms and it worked thank you

Comment: Figured as much. You can upvote and mark this answer as correct so others who come across this question experiencing the same issue know the problem and how to fix it.